# Generated jar in jdk8 on Linux platform, and always return null through jarFile.getJarEntry("pacakge_name") on Windows platform

Tags: java

1. HelloWorld.java

   ```
    package com.perjoker;
    public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("HelloWorld");
    }
    }
   ```
2. javac com/perjoker/HelloWorld.java
3. jar cvf Hello.jar com/perjoker/HelloWorld.class
4. copy Hello.jar to windows
5. The following code always returns null when executed on the windows platform, which is very confusing. If Hello.jar is generated on the windows platform, the following code can return correctly

```
    JarFile jarFile = new JarFile("Hello.jar");
    JarEntry jarEntry = jarFile.getJarEntry("com/perjoker");
```

Answer (score 1):

- These are two ways to use the jar command

  ```
  jar --help 
  Example 1: to archive two class files into an archive called classes.jar:
         jar cvf classes.jar Foo.class Bar.class
  Example 2: use an existing manifest file 'mymanifest' and archive all the
             files in the foo/ directory into 'classes.jar':
         jar cvfm classes.jar mymanifest -C foo/ .
  ```

  - Example 1: The jar package will be generated without directory information，As shown below

    ```
    λ jar tf Hello_WSL.jar
    META-INF/
    META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    com/perjoker/HelloWorld.class
    ```
  - Example 2: The jar package will be generated with directory information，As shown below

    ```
    λ jar tf Hello_windows.jar
    META-INF/
    META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    com/
    com/perjoker/
    com/perjoker/HelloWorld.class
    com/perjoker/HelloWorld.java
    ```

Therefore, if you use Example 2 to generate the jar, there is no problem.